# How to check user role in MVC 5 identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I create a EF code first database identity system with custom roles. When i register a user i put him in a role, and in the database i can see that works on the AspNetUserRoles table.

But when i try to check the user role using User.IsInRole("admin") i.e, it always return false( i tried with low, upper, all the way case). 
I need to put something in the webconfig? Or what im missing here? Its my first time developing with this new Identity system and i think that is a bit confuse.

In my immediate window:

```
User.Identity.Name
"teste06"
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
true
User.IsInRole("admin")
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in     System.Data.dll
```

Exception:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Where are you calling User.IsInRole from?

Comment: @AlexDresko Im calling in a normal action after i made the login.

Comment: Have you checked User.Identity.Name, whether it contains the loggedin username or not ??

Comment: Ok, so you are getting exception when you are calling IsInRole function, i think you should check the inner exception it could contains the more detail error message, post the inner exception message also ?

Comment: +1 to @gaurav's comment. Also, is this a brand new MVC project?

Comment: I get a connection network error of sql. I can create user, make login, create roles, add users to roles, everything. But i cant check the user Roles

Comment: can you post inner exception message ??

Comment: @gaurav Ive posted, thanks!

Comment: @gaurav i think is something missing in the webconfig, dont you?

Comment: @gaurav i need to specify the rolemanager in web.config?

Comment: @AlexDresko Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419899/using-asp-net-identity-on-mvc-5-project-but-httpcontext-user-providername-is-as?rq=1

Comment: If you're trying to write code inside a controller that handles user authentication and authorization, try using an instance of `UserManager` to determine whether the user is in a role. Something like: `UserManager.IsInRole(dbUser.Id, roleName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the role Manager Is Activated 
and it is trying to create an SQL Express Database
to validate roles, i 've had the same issue i solve it by adding this code to my 
web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you have this in your startup class

```
app.UseSignInCookies();
```

Also, I'm guessing your `DbContext` class is derived from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`or `IdentityDbContext`.

If not, make sure you do.

Look [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx) article for reference.

Similar post relating to your problem can be found [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1939748.aspx?Role%20Management%20in%20ASP%20MVC%205%20Microsoft%20AspNet%20Identity%20drives%20me%20mad%20)

Comment: Hi, the error is that i missed the rolemanager in the webconfig file. Thanks!

Comment: @ggui Then Leonardo's answer is the correct one? Mark it.