# Adding Roles to an existing Asp.net mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello everyone,
               I implemented my own registration and login system to a blog application i was writing. I used the database first approach and created some tables (dbo.UserProfiles - containing user information) and other tables with which i generated an entity data model from . However i got to a stage where i needed to create an admin panel and then i realized that i needed a way to associate each user to a specific role (Moderator, administrator, guest) and restrict access to certain pages based on those roles. 
    My question is that how can i implement a role provider to an existing database since i did not use the default membership system of asp.net mvc and also i can i use the roles to allow or restrict access to certain pages in my website.

Comment: Do you have another table for roles and third table to define user roles?

Comment: @mGouda yes i created a table called dbo.roles with roleId and roleName column and also a table called dbo.UsersInRoles with columns roleId and UserId and specified the foreign key relationship. After that i clicked on the edmx designer and updated  my existing model to include the newly added tables. Then i created a new controller called adminController which i added an [Authorize(Role="Admin")] attribute. Upon navigating to this page i got an error saying 'A network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to the sql server.

Comment: the error you are talking about here has nothing related to the original question, this error indicates you cannot connect to sql server database, double check connectionstring and related stuff

Comment: ok @mGouda what is the best way to achieve the question i asked that is about adding roles to an existing website that already has a membership system (not implementing the default membership system of asp.net mvc).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own membership provider by inheriting from the MembershipProvider class.  MSDN has a great sample on how to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa(v=vs.100).aspx

You will also need to implment a Role Provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tksy7hd7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i already created a membership system and ive gone far with the application that i cant throw away my membership system and start implementing the default one provided by asp.net mvc. What i need is a way to add a role provider to my existing database   and sync it with the existing custom membership system i created.

Comment: If you follow the examples found at MSDN that I've posted you can create a custom membership provider that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom principal and identity. Implement IsInRole method. Authenticate your request in global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest method. And then just add `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` atribute to your specified actions.

Here is a good [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF) and [ansver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305/1235390).

Comment: that i think is the way, only problem is i'm new to this technology and i dont know how to go about it. can you help with some code?

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to specify that a controller is only available to users in the Administrators roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    . . .
}
```

The following example shows how to limit access to an action inside a controller to only the specified list of roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Moderators,Administrator")]
public List<myObject> GetRestrictedData()
{
    . . .
}
```

The following example shows how to limit access to a controller to only the specified users.

```
[Authorize(Users="Jhon,Games")]
public class RestrictedContentController : Controller
{
    . . .
}
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: i used the first method above and i got an error saying "a network related or instance specific error occured". I'm confused because this only started happening after i added those two tables and updated my model. since other pages in the application requiring connection to the database are working fine without any problem. only the page i added [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] is causing this error.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue, but I recommend you review steps you did after adding new tables (roles, userRoles) like creating edmk and related controllers and views etc. also, check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996191/how-to-check-user-role-in-mvc-5-identity)